# How to put a whole part of generated HTML from htlatex in a special div?

Tags: tex4ht, css

Using TeX files, I generate two pdf deliverables and one website from the same source.

I generate my `html` using `htxelatex` and a `config` file like that has the following:

```
\Css { .tableofcontents {
  float:left;
  top:20px;
  padding-left:2%;
  width:30%;
  background:#eee;
  font-size:1em;
  }
}
\Css { .container {
  float:left;
  top:20px;
  padding-left:15px;
  width:65\%;
  height:1024px;
  }
}
```

This what I just add the following to my generated HTML using scripting

```
<div class="container">
   <--! The whole tex code except the tableofcontents -->
</div>
```

And now I have a gorgeous `HTML` with the table of contents on one half of the screen and the content on the other one.

It works
I was just wondering if there is a way to add the whole body in the div automatically from the config file somehow. When I generate the `html`, the `tableofcontents` is inside the body so I can't use `body` object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to solve three problems:

1. Contents heading is outside the `.tableofcontents` div, so it doesn't float together
2. Add `<div class="container">` after `\tableofcontents`
3. Add closing `</div>` before `<body>` element

First two of them are pretty easy to solve with config file like this:

```
\edef\hash{\string#}
\Preamble{xhtml}

\Configure{tableofcontents}
   {\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{<div class="tableofcontents"\csname a:LRdir\endcsname><h3 class="likesectionHead">Contents</h3>}\IgnorePar}
   {\ifTag{tex4ht-body}{\HCode{<br />}\Link{tex4ht-body}{}Home\EndLink}{}}
   {\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{</div><div class="container">}\ShowPar}
   {\HCode{<br />}}   {}

\Css { .tableofcontents{ 
  float:left;
  top:20px;
  padding-left:2\%;
  width:30\%;
  background:\hash eee;
  font-size:1em;
  }
}
\Css { .container {
  float:left;
  top:20px;
  padding-left:15px;
  width:65\%;
  height:1024px;
  }
}
\begin{document}
\let\contentsname=\empty
\EndPreamble
```

With `\let\contentsname=\empty` you suppress printing the contents title, which is then printed inside `.tableofcontents` div. I copied `\Configure{tableofcontents}` from `html4.4ht` file and just added `<h3 class="likesectionHead">Contents</h3>` and `<div class="container">` into right places.

Also note that I modified your `css` instructions, characters `%` and `#` need to be escaped.

Last task is the hardest. You can use `\Configure{BODY}{body start}{body end}` to insert closing `</div>`, but if you look at configurations of `BODY` in `html4.4ht` file, you can see that lot of things happens there and you may break something, if you just use `\Configure{BODY}{\HCode{<body>}}{\HCode{</div></body>}}`. I suggest to postprocess the html file with `tidy` command:

```
tidy -m -utf8 filename.html
```

For sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Intro}

Just try some random paragraph

\section{Some environments}

\subsection{verbatim}

\begin{verbatim}
    echo "verbatim"
\end{verbatim}

\subsection{quotation}
\begin{quotation}
hello from quotation
\end{quotation}
\end{document}
```

[image]